# R Markdown preview LaTeX by scrolling over

Tags: r

I believe in the past I have been able to preview my LaTeX code in R Markdown by just placing the cursor over the LaTeX chunk, but right now I'm unable to recreate that. Any idea how to turn that back on?

Thanks!

Comment: That must be particular to the IDE you're using. You'll have to find their issue tracker/mailing list to resolve/question that.

Comment: Is this a question about RStudio? I've never seen such functionality myself.

Comment: @werner not necessarily. We answer lots of IDE specific questions here. But we do need to know the editor.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, this is a feature of Rstudio (and only of Rstudio?) that still work,at least in Version 1.1.463, **but only for inline equations**, not for any LaTeX chunk.

[image: capture1]

To have this preview be that this is enabled menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Global Options</kbd> > <kbd>R markdown</kbd>:

[image: capture2]

Or for a single document in the configuration button:

[image: capture]